# sudo pip install error

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with pip version 1.0 and python version 2.7.

```
pip --version
pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Unfortunately, since trying to upgrade one of the pip packages, I'm unable to install anything using pip.  I'm getting the following error messages:

```
vince@hal:~$ sudo pip install glances
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 215, in run
    import setuptools
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Storing complete log in /home/vince/.pip/pip.log
vince@hal:~$ sudo pip install flexget
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 215, in run
    import setuptools
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Storing complete log in /home/vince/.pip/pip.log
vince@hal:~$
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: How you installed pip? and the contents of the log file?

Comment: You might see if you have /usr/share/doc/python-pip/distribute_setuptools.rst on your system (mine came with python-pip).  It explains a possible cause of this and gives a solution (which from a cursory look appears to be the same you found from the support ticket).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/429417/no-module-named-setuptools-setuptools-is-already-the-newest-version seems to have it solved in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get it working - hopefully this will help others in the future:

Found the following ticket:

http://flexget.com/ticket/21161

From here I used the following command:

> This was because the upgrade somehow managed to remove the setuptools
>   package from my python environment. Running the command below fixed
>   setuptools and allowed me to use pip to uninstall and reinstall
>   flexget.
>
> curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py |
>   sudo python

Successfully installed flexget

Cleaning up...

```
vince@hal:~$ flexget -V

1.2.125
```

You are on the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Comment: Didn't work.  I've already got it installed:

vince@hal:~$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
python-setuptools is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

Comment: and when you installing setuptools via pip, what is happening?
sudo pip install setuptools

Answer (score 0):

First of all install python-setuptools

```
apt install python-setuptools
```

then try

```
easy_install glances
```